# ReactJS show/hide button not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications

I have a section in a React webapp that looks like this:

```
<div style={ sidebarControlStyle }>
    Minimum ORF Size: { minimumOrfSize }                
    { readOnly ? null : 
        <div id='orfControl' onClick={function() {showOrfModal = true;}}> Change </div>                       
    }
    { showOrfModal ? 
        <div id='orfModal'>
            <input id='orfInput' type='number' defaultValue={ minimumOrfSize }/>
            <button name='setOrfMin' onTouchTap={function () {
                var newMinVal = document.getElementById('orfInput').value;
                signals.changeOrfMin({ newMin: newMinVal });
                showOrfModal = false;
            }}>Set</button>
            <button name='closeOrfModal' onClick={ function() {showOrfModal = false
            }}>Cancel</button>
        </div> : null 
    }
</div>
```

This section controls a variable called `minimumOrfSize` that should be changeable by the user.
What I want this to do is display a "change" button that, when clicked, displays a modal where you can enter a new value and click "Set" to change that value. The `signals` is a reference to a cerebral controller signal that'll change that value in the state tree. Right now, clicking the "Change" button does nothing. Am I referencing something incorrectly? I'm fairly new to React.

Comment: What happens when you do 
onClick ={function(e) {console.log("onClick", e);}} ?

Comment: I see the "onClick" message and a SyntheticMouseEvent being called by (program), so it's registering the click so that's good. I did notice if I log showOrfModal it has value true, so it's being set but that modal div isn't rendering.

Comment: Please provide a version of cerebral you use and how you have connected it to state. BTW, you are able to use Cerebral Debugger Extension to get better insight what is hapenning in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a React guru but i would probably go the 'state' way.

```
this.state = {
    showModal: false,
    this._onButtonClick = this._onButtonClick.bind(this);
};
```

the function that changes the state

```
_onButtonClick() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: true
    });
}
```

In the button we call the the function to change the state

```
<div id='orfControl' onClick={this._onButtonClick}> Change </div>
```

and then the part where you actually render your modal

```
{this.state.showModal ?
    <MyModal /> :
    null
}
```

I haven't tested the above but you should manage to make it work :)
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide full class and cerebral version to be able to answer this properly.

Some advice though:

- Try to understand react's `setState` first before using state management.
- Try to make smaller render functions either with instance methods or more components.
- Do try cerebral, it is so elegant and IMHO better that redux.**
- To use the cerebral-debugger you need to download it from [here](https://github.com/cerebral/cerebral-debugger/releases). The chrome extension is deprecated (and at least in ubuntu I wasn't able to make it work)**

** Overmind is a new state management lib made by cerebral's creator. I recomend trying that instead (as long as IE support is not needed)